# Rails ajax/partial not rendering properly

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to test using AJAX to list a downloaded item in rails. And everything up until the partial seems to work correctly. The only thing I can get it to return is and ID element, so `download.id` works or even `download.someotherobject.id` works (in a :belongs_to relationship, for example). But if I try to pull any of the other attributes (like the token attribute in my example below) from the download object, it just fails silently. I don't get any errors in the log or the javascript console.

My method for testing:

```
def download
    @download = Download.find(15)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {@download}
    end

 end
```

My download.js.erb:

```
$('#start_download_link').after(<%= render(@download) %>);
```

My downloads/_download.html.erb

```
<%= download.token %>
```

Here's the log:

```
Started GET "/start/download" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-12-09 21:09:22 -0500
21:09:22 web.1     |   Processing by StartController#download as JS
21:09:22 web.1     |   Download Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "downloads".* FROM "downloads" WHERE "downloads"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 15]]
21:09:22 web.1     | Rendered downloads/_download.html.erb (0.1ms)
21:09:22 web.1     | Rendered start/download.js.erb (22.3ms)
21:09:22 web.1     | Completed 200 OK in 119ms (Views: 30.8ms | ActiveRecord: 2.7ms)
```

Except, I get nothing in rendered in the view. But, again `download.id` does render the id. I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: how about other html elements in html.erb?

Answer (score 0):

If `download.id` is working but `download.token` is not, try checking if the field for if the token is set to null.

Comment: No, it's not. It has something to do with the way the js is escaped, because not building it through a partial (directly in the js file) has worked, but with some manual escaping.